# jQuery. from child to parent

Tags: jquery, html

How do i make jquery fadeOut parent element? I've got automatically generated `<dt>` , each `<dl>` has similar class. and there's remove buttons, with same classes, in each  tag. My last attempt didn't work out -

```
$('a.ajax_cart_block_remove_link').click(function({
    $('a.ajax_cart_block_remove_link').parents('dt.left_cart').fadeOut(600);

});
```

It removes all `<dl>` tags of my `<dt>`, when i need to remove only parent of remove button i just clicked on.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell for certain but you probably want :

```
$('a.ajax_cart_block_remove_link').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('dt.left_cart').fadeOut(600);
});
```